# Why is only one function called from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp

Working with javascript I met with a problem. There is a javascript with two functions, one disabbed checkbox for one class name, and the other for another. But on the jsp page only one works (specifically check).

```
function pilotCB(p) {  //this dosen't work
    var b = document.getElementsByClassName('p');
    var checkValue = p.checked;
    for (j = 0; j < b.length; j++) { // iterate from 0 instead of 1
        if (b[j] != p){// if checkbox is selected.
            b[j].disabled = p.checked;// disable others
        }
    }
}
function check(self) { //this work
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('cb'); // get elements by class name
    var checkValue = self.checked;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { // iterate from 0 instead of 1
        if (a[i] != self){// if checkbox is selected.
            a[i].disabled = self.checked;// disable others
        }
    }
}
```

JSP page, part where the call is made:

```
<c:forEach items="${pilotList}" varStatus="i">
                        <c:set var="navigator" value="${navigatorList[i.index].name}"/>
                        <c:set var="radioOperator" value="${radioOperatorList[i.index].name}"/>
                        <c:set var="stewardess" value="${stewardessList[i.index].name}"/>
                        <tr>
                            <td>${pilotList[i.index].name}<input class="p" type="checkbox"  name="itemId" value="${pilot[i.index].id}" onchange="pilotCB(this)"/></td>
                            <td>${navigator}<input class="n" type="checkbox"  name="itemId" value="${item.id}" onchange="checkN(this)"/></td>
                            <td>${radioOperator}<input class="cb" type="checkbox"  name="itemId" value="${radioOperatorList[i.index].id}" onchange="check(this)"/></td>
                            <td>${stewardess}<input class="s" type="checkbox"  name="itemId" value="${item.id}" onchange="checkS(this)"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
```

Why does only one work I can not understand?

Comment: the function doesn't get called at all?

Comment: Because `self` has a different context.

Comment: @Jonathan Laliberte function is called, but nothing happens.

Comment: @Obsidian Age I do not quite understand what that means? Can be a little more detaile, please) If I take the first function in a separate file, everything works. I also tried to comment the first method and replaced cb by p on the second, but the second method is still a disabled cb

Comment: To get more info, change onchange="pilotCB(this)" to onchange="pilotCB('ckbox1');" and add id="ckbox1" to the checkbox.

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: I"m lost and don't have any help. Maybe there is a name conflict. Try changing p to self in pilotCB. Try changing pilotCB to zpilotCB. Do console.log(p) and console.log(self) as the first instructions. Is the first checkbox disabled? Log its .disabled.